# iPhone 6, iPhone 5s get assertion failed

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, testflight, iphone-6

Application works fine when I'm running on an actual device via usb but when I start through testflight can not connect to the network looked in the logs there! for iphone 4s and everything works fine through testfligh
and via usb

```
Mar 31 22:51:07 iPhone-Lechi amfid[178] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Mar 31 22:51:07 iPhone-Lechi kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[296] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6E693EC9-13D6-45C6-9BE6-BE985B774606 (sandbox)
Mar 31 22:51:07 iPhone-Lechi amfid[178] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Mar 31 22:51:07 iPhone-Lechi locationd[60] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Mar 31 22:51:07 iPhone-Lechi amfid[178] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Mar 31 22:51:07 iPhone-Lechi amfid[178] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Mar 31 22:51:07 iPhone-Lechi amfid[178] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Mar 31 22:51:07 iPhone-Lechi amfid[178] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Mar 31 22:51:07 iPhone-Lechi amfid[178] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Mar 31 22:51:07 iPhone-Lechi amfid[178] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Mar 31 22:51:07 iPhone-Lechi amfid[178] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Mar 31 22:51:08 iPhone-Lechi amfid[178] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Mar 31 22:51:08 iPhone-Lechi FIT[296] <Error>: assertion failed: 12D508: libxpc.dylib + 71792 [3C982BC2-5B46-305A-9A09-3C3D15332820]: 0x7d
Mar 31 22:51:08 iPhone-Lechi Unknown[296] <Error>: 
Mar 31 22:51:08 iPhone-Lechi locationd[60] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
```

Comment: You tested your application using development provisioning and on test flight you are using App store provisioning yeah ?